# Get .textContent clonned on some div. Show with mouseOver/out function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning community, I would like to know if someone can help me with this problem.

My idea is the following: Each image in the homepage section (8 images), has associated:

```
<div id="project__caption" class="relative -z-10 hidden">
 <p>Your description image here</p>
</div>
```

Which I pass to clone and store into a new div created as #cursor-outer.

I have done this code to achieve the above explained:

```
cursorText: function () {
      if (!isMobile() || !isTouchDevice()) {
        const projectCap = document.querySelectorAll("#project__caption");
        const cursorText = document.getElementById("cursor-outer");

        for (let i = 0; i < projectCap.length; i++) {
          const element = projectCap[i];
          const clonned = cursorText.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
          clonned.classList.add("is-inactive");
        }    
      }
    },
```

Every time I use the mouseOver / mouseOut function I need to get this new  and display it only above this image, and then hide it when i move cursor out image.

So i need now to make 2 functions like : mouseOver / mouseOut,
Can anyone help me to get this code transform to vanilla js (actually working with jquery)

```
function mouseOver() {
  var hoveredProject = $(this).find(".project__caption").text();
  var hoveredProjectActive = $(
    "#cursor-outer .project__caption:contains('" + hoveredProject + "')"
  );
  $(hoveredProjectActive).filter(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === hoveredProject) {
      $(this).removeClass("is-inactive").addClass("is-active");
    }
});
function mouseOut() {
  var hoveredProject = $(this).find(".project__caption").text();
  var hoveredProjectActive = $(
    ".project__caption:contains('" + hoveredProject + "')"
  );
  hoveredProjectActive.removeClass("is-active").addClass("is-inactive");
}
```

Thanks to anyone in advance, appreciate any help :)